# Two UINavigationItems?

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem

Could anyone explain why there are two `navigationItems`? When I log like below:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationItem);
NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController.navigationItem);
```

I get two different instances of `UINavigationItem`:

```
<UINavigationItem: 0x7f85b06f5a20>
<UINavigationItem: 0x7f85b06ab640>
```

I have only created a `UINavigationController` programmatically once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `UIViewController`s have a property `navigationItem`. Therefore, because `UINavigationController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, it also has this property.

`self.navigationItem` will be the one presented when your controller is pushed. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/navigationItem) for `navigationItem`, it's clear about this property

> This is a unique instance of UINavigationItem created to represent the view controller when it is pushed onto a navigation controller.

`self.navigationController.navigationItem` *would* be the item displayed if Apple allowed `UINavigationController`s to be nested. However, since this isn't allowed, it's best to forget about it.

Comment: Why is `self.navigationController.navigationItem` initialised then if realistically it isn't used? I am mostly confused by the fact that there are two initialised `navigationItems`.

Comment: According to the docs: "The first time the property is accessed, the UINavigationItem object is created.". It's only initialized because you're accessing it!

Comment: You mean it gets created because I am NSLog'ing it? Because that's the only time I ever tried accessing it.

Comment: A small correction: to allow `UISplitViewController` support in compact size class devices, it is now possible to push a navigation controller in another navigation controller, but still, the navigation controller's navigation item is not used, but the top controller's.

Comment: What makes you say that navigation controllers can't be nested?

Comment: @artooras Yes, when you say `self.navigationController.navigationItem` that's when the instance is created.

Comment: @jlehr I don't believe they can be nested, because when I try it always crashes: `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this question puzzled me for awhile but I think I figured it out. `self.navigationItem` and `self.navigationController.navigationItem` are two different objects. Here's why:

In iOS, each `UIViewController` object has a `UINavigationItem`. The navigationItem for your current view controller is `self.navigationController`, and `self.navigationController.navigationItem` is kind of a spillover object, it's the navigationItem for your parent navigationController.